# prediction of bounding boxes from grid in yolo

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, computer-vision, object-detection

in deeplearning.ai andrew-ng says

[image with grid overlay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vurGa.jpg)

Yolo uses a grid overlay architecture and a grid cell is responsible for detecting an object if it contains the midpoint of object with some probability assosciated with it

how can such a small grid cell gives high  class probability for bounding boxes with the center of the object, and low class probability for the for bounding box from the grid cell which is not the center of the object, so how grid cell is going to decide that probability without looking into an entire image

the size of grid wont even match the necessary input size for pre-trained object detector ,then how can yolo detect and classify that the grid has object and no object

for example  grid cells of background and a car in an image

Comment: the perceptive field of each grid cell is much bigger. The grid cells are a virtual construct in yolo, which only have two purposes: 1. describing the output of the fully convolutional network 2. describing the context of the used output bins (anchor box bins). A nice property of the fully convolutional network is, that each of the outputs works the same, so in theory it doesnt matter much whether the object is at the top-left or at the bottom-right of the image, another output would just interpret the same valued features at the other location. The sampling of those outputs is the grid

Comment: Micka you mean to say that , features which were extracted and learned by the network are saved and compared with those grid features during the testing time is that what you want to say

Comment: the last layer outputs of the feature-extractor layers are the grid cells. Since the neural network is like a pyramid, the image pixels which have an effect on those features are spread much further than the grid cells (that's called the perceptive field of that output).

Comment: try to forget about the grid cells as some kind of image region. It is a 2d output position of the neural network. If you want to find out, how many input pixels were used to compute that output information, you have to track back the used filters in the networ, e.g. every 3x3 convolution folter increases the perceptive field by 1 in every direction. Take care of things like pooling layers or stride, which have their own effect on the perceptive field.